# Ubuntu AMD Graphics card Drivers (AMD r9 275)

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, amd-catalyst

I have a Lenovo y40-80 with an AMD Radeon R9 275 graphics card.  I installed the AMD Catalyst Control drivers on Ubuntu Gnome, but in my settings it says my graphics card is a TROPO XTX (6820).

Here is my openGL information after running glmark2

```
======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     ATI Technologies Inc.
    GL_RENDERER:   TROPO XTX (6820)
    GL_VERSION:    4.4.12968 Compatibility Profile Context 14.201.1006.1002
=======================================================
```

Also glmark2 shows a lower FPS & score than the Intel graphics (though it does seem to have a higher quality and looks better).

Is this normal? Should I change or update anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD uses code names to distinguish their GPUs in house and those often show up in the drivers etc. I couldn't find anything specifying the R9 (m?)275 specifically but "Tropo XTX" looks like a similar style name to the ones used in their other chips for example "Venus XTX" is the R9 m275X. Also 6820 follows their old GPU naming conventions so even though an HD 6820 didn't exist that could indicate that this mobile GPU is based on an older 6800 series desktop GPU which would also make sense. It's not concrete evidence but I think it's enough not to be worried about that.

As for lower FPS score, is that lower using the exact same settings for the test? If the settings were turned up or something then that could happen. I am not particularly familiar with glmark, I usually use Firestrike.

Comment: now that I’ve run apt-get update and switched to the new version of Ubuntu Gnome(15) it was fixed and now says AMD Radeon R9 M275X.. not sure exactly what did it but it seems to actually work even better now : )